# How do I set up a SharePoint 2016 farm to work with AOAG?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

My college and I have successfully set up AOAG groups on MS SQL 2019 Server, but when we try using failover with SharePoint 2016, SharePoint stops working.

We've hade issues finding a complete tutorial in this matter on the Internet and needs some hands on suggestions about how to set it up or a referral to a working tutorial.

Comment: OK, actually found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-an-alwayson-availability-group :)